# php - how to increment count for above 80% similarity in substr

Tags: php, string, substring, similarity

I am using the following codes to count occurrence of substring.

```
$post= "abcdefgh abc abcd ";
$value= "abc";
$count= substr_count($post,$value);
echo $count;
```

But I want to customise a little like if any word doesn't match more than 80% I do not want to increment count variable,similarly if any word doesn't match 100% but there is above 80% similarity I would like to increment count variable.For this I need to get similarity(%) first. how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option might be to remove all occurrences of the search string, and then display the ratio of characters matched to total characters:

```
$post = "abcdefgh abc abcd ";
$value = "abc";
$percent = 100.0*(strlen($post) - strlen(str_replace($value, "", $post))) / strlen($post);
echo "percent similarity: " . $percent;
```

### Demo

If you instead want to find out how many times `abc` appeared in the text, we can try a similar strategy:

```
$num_matches = (strlen($post) - strlen(str_replace($value, "", $post))) / strlen($value);
echo "number of matches: " . $num_matches;
```

Comment: Now your requirements are confusing me, in particular the `abcd` over 80% part.  What output do you actually want here?